# Manage boolean condition with Include in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I know is a simple problem, but I don't find the way to manage this properly. I think it's ugly, and I'm sure a better way exists.

```
    public async Task<List<DocumentCategory>> GetAll(bool includeDocumentTypes = false, bool includeDocumentDescriptions = false)
    {
        if (!includeDocumentTypes && !includeDocumentDescriptions)
        {
            return await _context.DocumentCategories.ToListAsync();
        }
        else if (includeDocumentTypes && !includeDocumentDescriptions)
        {
            return await _context.DocumentCategories.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes).ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return await _context.DocumentCategories.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes).ThenInclude(dt => dt.DocumentDescriptions).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
```

The goal is to include nested datas from boolean flags.

More information about my class below :

```
public class DocumentCategoriesRepository : GenericRepository<DocumentCategory>, IDocumentCategoriesRepository
{
    public DocumentCategoriesRepository(myDbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    // Here is my method
}
```

Comment: Delegate the responsibility of including navigation properties to callers. So make your `GetAll` accept an `IQueryable<DocumentCategory>` instead of condition parameters

Comment: Unless boolean arguments are passed dynamically - create own methods for every case

Comment: @nbokmans, in OP case if `IQueryable` is returned then whole method `GetAll` become redundant.

Comment: @Fabio that is because in my opinion it is - what is the reason for a `GetAll` if the `All` depends on which parameters are passed?

Comment: If only we stopped trying to wrap EF into a second repository layer...

Comment: I agree with @Fabio. Wrapping EF into an repository and then letting the caller again know that EF is behind that repository by letting him pass parameters for including makes having a repository unnecessary. Either use EF directly or let the repository do it's job and decide from where and how it gets the desired data.

Comment: This method is in my repository. I don't want to let the responsability to the caller because is it another layer (API in fact). I need filters because it's avoid to declare three different paths.

Comment: @BaptX But in fact you are already giving the responsability to the API layer. The API shouldn't know about including things as this is database specific code. If you are returning "incomplete" objects where some properties are null and may not be accessed in the API because they were not loaded then your data access logic is alread leaking into the API. For cases in which some navigations are not needed and shall therefore not be loaded it is best to use a specific "ReadModel" object which just does not have that navigation so the caller is not responsible for knowing what has been loaded.

Comment: @Nannanas you're right on your mindset : I can get all datas from databases and use dtos to filter the wanted datas on the API layer. But I have to declare three different dtos. Two ways of thinking. My question is not a good example about our discussion because no business logic appears between api layer and database layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
public async Task<List<DocumentCategory>> GetAll(bool includeDocumentTypes = false, bool includeDocumentDescriptions = false)
    {
        var categories =  _context.DocumentCategories.AsQueryable();

        if (includeDocumentTypes)
        {
            categories = categories.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes);
        }

        if (includeDocumentDescriptions)
        {
            categories = categories
                              .Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes)
                              .ThenInclude(dt => dt.DocumentDescriptions);
        }

        return await categories.ToListAsync();
    }
```

This should work as including `DocumentTypes` multiple times is not a problem for EF and is handled as if it was included just once.

Comment: And now you have the same `Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes)` twice. Not really much cleaner, is it?

Comment: @CodeCaster I think it is because its much more readable without multiple return statements and && in the if conditions. Including it multiple times is quite normal when working with EF. Imaginge having to include multiple navigations on `DocumentType` then you would also have to include document types multiple times.

Comment: I explicitly disagree with you on the "much more readable". The duplicated code also causes worse maintainability.

Comment: @CodeCaster it is at leat much more maintainable than the original snippet as there was much more duplicated code in there. As I said having to include a property multiple times cannot really be avoided when using EF as long as you do not want to have a lot of variables just containing intermediate results (which in my opinion does not improve readability).

Comment: It's the same problem as the answer above : CS0266 Impossible de convertir implicitement le type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<API.Models.DocumentCategory, System.Collections.Generic.List<API.Models.DocumentType>>' en 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<API.Models.DocumentCategory>'. Une conversion explicite existe (un cast est-il manquant ?)

Comment: @BaptX I updated my answer - now you shoudn't have this problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, where you build up the query in distinct steps.

**CAVEAT - This code hasn't been tested and may not work out of the box. The type of `query` would likely need some work**

```
public async Task<List<DocumentCategory>> GetAll(bool includeDocumentTypes = false, bool includeDocumentDescriptions = false)
{
    var query = _context.DocumentCategories;

    if (includeDocumentTypes)
    {
        query = query.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes);

        if (includeDocumentDescriptions)
        {
            query = query.ThenInclude(dt => dt.DocumentDescriptions);
        }
    }

    return await query.ToListAsync()
}
```

Comment: The `DocumentDescriptions` are on `DOcumentTypes`, not `DocumentCategories`, notice the `ThenInclude()`.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Updated

Comment: And that won't compile because `query` isn't a `IIncludableQueryable<TEntity,IEnumerable<TPreviousProperty>>`. :P

Comment: @phuzi this will still not work as `query` if of type `DbSet<DocumentCategory>` on which `ThenInclude(dt => dt.DocumentDescriptions)` cannot be used as it is a property of `DocumentType`

Comment: @Nannanas I did say it likely would not work out of the box but this is probably closer to what OP was after to tidy up their code.

Comment: @CodeCaster you're right :p

CS0266 Impossible de convertir implicitement le type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<API.Models.DocumentCategory, System.Collections.Generic.List<API.Models.DocumentType>>' en 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<API.Models.DocumentCategory>'. Une conversion explicite existe (un cast est-il manquant ?)

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple edits like below

```
public async Task<List<DocumentCategory>> GetAll(bool includeDocumentTypes = false, bool includeDocumentDescriptions = false)
        {
            var lstCategoires = _context.DocumentCategories;

            if (includeDocumentTypes)
            {
                 lstCategoires = includeDocumentDescriptions ? lstCategoires.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes).ThenInclude(dt => dt.DocumentDescriptions) :
                                                               lstCategoires = lstCategoires.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes);
            }

            return await lstCategoires.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: you are checking `includeDocumentDescriptions` twice so the else part  `lstCategoires = lstCategoires.Include(dc => dc.DocumentTypes)` will never be executed

Comment: sorry by mistake when enhance and optimize the code, I update it just removed second if condition

Comment: Same problem as different answers : CS0029 Impossible de convertir implicitement le type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<API.Models.DocumentCategory, System.Collections.Generic.List<API.Models.DocumentDescription>>' en 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<API.Models.DocumentCategory>'

Comment: Answer updated, please check it again I just removed additional ToListAsync() in condition